# Jensen's inequality: proof by using linear functions

Tags: probability, inequality, convex-analysis

[image]

Here's an extract from Stochastic Calculus for Finance Volume 1 by Shreve.

I don't understand the statement that says

> a convex function is the maximum of all linear functions that lie below it.

I just find it confusing because it tries to define a convex function by linear functions.

I think I don't understand $2.2.1$, defining $\phi(x)$ by linear functions.

Comment: It doesn't _define_ $\varphi$ by linear functions.  Let $\psi$ be any function such that there exists at least one (affine) linear function $\lambda$ with $\lambda(x) \leqslant \psi(x)$ for all $x$. Then define $$\operatorname{env}(\psi) \colon x \mapsto \sup \left\{ \mu(x) : \mu \text{ is affine linear and } \bigl(\forall y\bigr)\bigl(\mu(y) \leqslant \psi(y)\bigr)\right\}.$$ Then $(2.2.1)$ says that for convex $\varphi$, we have $\operatorname{env}(\varphi) = \varphi$.

Comment: I understand what you write until ... for all x. 

What does env($\psi$) mean?

Comment: $\operatorname{env}(\psi)$ is a function we define. Let's call it the lower envelope of $\psi$. Its value at $x$ is the supremum of all values $\mu(x)$, where $\mu$ is an affine linear function that is $\leqslant \psi$. Thus by definition, we have $\operatorname{env}(\psi) \leqslant \psi$ [that means the inequality holds pointwise]. Now the thing is that for convex functions, the inequality is in fact an equality.

Comment: I think I don't understand the set notation that says "the maximum of all linear functions". You're using sup instead of max, I think it has the same meaning. And I don't see how does the convexity is defined there.

Comment: A maximum is a supremum that is attained. For convex functions, the supremum in question is always attained, so one can write $\max$. In general, it could be that the supremum is not attained for some $x$ for a given function $\psi$, so I can't write $\max$ and must use $\sup$. Convexity is not defined here. This is just another characterisation of convex functions, $\psi$ is convex if and only if $\operatorname{env}(\psi) = \psi$.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the difference between maximum and supremum.

But I still don't get the meaning of the statement. 

It the statement 2.2.1, we also have another $\phi$. I assume that it could be any function as you said...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18434/discussion-between-afiqjohari-and-daniel-fischer).